# Highest $n$ such that $2^n|a^{2012}+a^{2013}+a^{2014}+\cdots +a^{3012}$,$a=4k+2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

A question from BdMO 2013 Nationals:

> Let  $a$  be an  integer  divisible by  2  but not  divisible  by  4. What is the  largest positive integer  n  such that  $2^n|a^{2012}+a^{2013}+a^{2014}+\dots +a^{3012}$?

I simply rewrote $a^{2012}+a^{2013}+a^{2014}+\dots +a^{3012}$ as $a^{2012}(1+a+a^2+\dots +a^{1000})$. The second factor is odd.Therefore by Euclid's lemma,$2^n|a^{2012}$. We know that $a$ is of the form $4k+2$,$k=0,1,\dots$. This implies that $2^n|(4k+2)^{2012}$ and therefore $2^n|2^{2012}*(2k+1)^{2012}$. Again by Euclid's lemma,$2^n$ must divide $2^{2012}$. The largest value of $n$ is therefore $2012$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: @AndréNicolas,thank you.If you have any improvements or suggestions to make my proof better,I would be happy to listen.

Comment: No change is needed. If I were marking the contest (and I have done a lot of that) I would give full marks. You might want to fix the typo in the title.

Comment: Short and sweet. Looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $a=2(2k+1)$. Hence,
$$f(a) = a^{2012} + a^{2013} + \cdots + a^{3012} = a^{2012}\left(1+a+\cdots+a^{1000}\right)$$
Since $a$ is even, we have $1+a+\cdots+a^{1000}$ is odd. Hence, the highest power of $2$ that divides $f(a)$, is the highest power of $2$ that divides $a^{2012}$.

---

What you have done is absolutely correct. Pat yourself on your back.